# Android design support library setup trouble

Tags: android, eclipse, androiddesignsupport

I'm completely confused with implementation of the Android design support library.  I tried to do almost everything advised on Stack Overflow, but I am still having compile-time errors on each widget from the design support library (Error parsing XML: Unbound prefix).

I'm developing in Eclipse.  Here's what have I done:

1. Downloaded last Android Support Library (23.0.1), Android Support Repository (21), API 23.
2. Imported `android-support-v7-appcompat` as a library,
   Project Properties - Android - Add.
3. Copied last downloaded `android-support-design.jar`,
   `android-support-v4.jar`,  `android-support-v7.jar`
   into `libs` folder of the project and imported them as:
   Profect Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries Add Jars and checked them on Order and Export.
4. I set up `targetSdkVersion="23"` in manifest,
       `target=android-23` in project.properties.
5. Changed theme in `styles.xml` as:

My layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: Why wouldnt you use Android studio

Comment: just got used to eclipse

Comment: Start using Android Studio adding libraries is so easy with gradle https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse

Comment: As someone who held out for a long time without switching to Android Studio, I can assure you that none of the suggested solutions work! YOu will have to switch to studio.

Comment: I see. But I cannot believe that nobody succeed with using of this library on eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start using Android Studio. The whole library management is very good of Android Studio. The support for eclipse is going to end from google so anyhow you have to switch.

Comment: Thank you. I will probably try to switch to android studio

Comment: Tried to configure eclipse but haven't succeed. This solution finally became the only right for me

Answer (score 1):

No doubt **Android Studio** is Good for Android development but still have a solution for this problem in eclipse. I have also face same problem then find solution like this.

It work for me hope same for You.

**First Step:-** find .aar file for **design-23.0.1.aar**

```
E:\new sdk\sdk\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design\23.0.1
```

**Second Step:-** copy that file and rename it like `design-23.0.1.jar` to be extract this.
After unzip it you find classes.jar, res, AndroidManifest etc and follow these steps: **Guided by** [***commonsware.com***](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html)

- Create an empty directory that will be the home for the Android
  library project. For the rest of these steps, I will refer to this as
  “the output directory”.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, **res/**, and **assets/** directories from the
  AAR into the output directory.
- Create a libs/ directory in the output directory. Copy into libs/ the
  `classes.jar` from the root of the unZIPped AAR, plus anything in libs/
  in the AAR (e.g., mediarouter-v7 has its own JAR of proprietary
  bits).
- Decide what build SDK you want to try to use. You might just choose
  the highest SDK version you have installed. Or, you can use the
  android:minSdkVersion and the -vNN resource set qualifiers to get
  clues as to what a good build SDK might be. If desired, create a
  project.properties file with a target=android-NNN line, where NNN is
  your chosen build SDK. Or, you can address this in Eclipse later on.
- Import the resulting project into Eclipse, and if needed adjust the
  build SDK (Project > Properties > Android). Also, you will need to
  attach to this library project any library projects it depends upon
  (e.g., mediarouter-v7 depends upon appcompat-v7).

Good Luck!

And Special thanks to [***commonsware***](https://commonsware.com/blog/) !!

Comment: Tank you very much for your answer. Tried your approach but struggled with importing project to exlipse (last item in the list). After importing i receive whole bunch of errors in console: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps' etc.

Comment: Have you added any jars into the libs/ of "output folder" or only classes.jar?  How have you imported the project?

Comment: @Leo this error is resolve after adding appcompact_v7 lib. just right click on design project -> properties -> android -> add appcompact_v7 lib. then clean design project .... and don't forget mark it as a library.

Comment: Thank you for yourhelp, but I haven't succeed and decided to switch to Android Studio. Here setting up libraries really takes just few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are attaching `android-support-v7-appcompat` for two times. Just use it only one time either use as library and add in properties OR put lib file in libs folder.

Just remove only one and try to clean and rebuild project again. 
:)

Comment: Unrtunatlely it doesn't help.